# IE - Form and all elements inside loosing id while using NVDA

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, internet-explorer, nvda

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doHKf.png)

When I'm turning on NVDA, one of my forms loosing IDs(and elements inside form). 
It only happens in IE (also when I'm turning off JS in browser).

```
<form name="frm239983213" class="comment-form" id="frm239983213"
  action="javascript:cs_contact_frm_submit(239983213)">
<div class="input-filed-contact"><label>Your Name</label> <i class="icon-user9"></i><input
        name="contact_name" class="  vsmall" id="contact_name" required="required" type="text"
        placeholder="Name" value=""></div>
<div class="input-filed-contact"><label>Email Address*</label><i class="icon-envelope4"></i><input
        name="contact_email" class="   vsmall" id="contact_email" required="" type="email"
        placeholder="Enter your email address" value=""></div>
<div class="input-filed-contact"><label>Subject</label><i class="icon-mobile4"></i><input
        name="contact_subject" class="form-control   vsmall" id="contact_subject" required="required"
        type="text" placeholder="Subject" value=""></div>
<div class="input-filed-contact"><label>Message</label> <textarea name="contact_msg"
                                                                  class="commenttextarea form-control  "
                                                                  id="contact_msg" required="required"
                                                                  placeholder="Message" rows="4" cols="39">Message</textarea>
</div>
<input id="hidden_239983213" type="hidden" value="239983213"><input id="suc_239983213" type="hidden"
                                                                    value="Success"><input
    id="err_239983213" type="hidden" value="Error"><input id="sendto_239983213" type="hidden"
                                                          value="x@y.com">
<div class="input-filed-contact">
    <div class="profile-contact-btn"><input name="submit" class="cs-bgcolor acc-submit"
                                            id="submit_btn239983213" type="submit" value="Submit Now"></div>
</div>
<div id="loading_div239983213" style="margin: 19px 0px 0px 100px; float: left;"></div>
```

Piece of html code. When I'm copying code after running NVDA, in clipboard those IDs are preserved, but browser hiding IDs. Developer tools:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5etG.png)

Comment: Can you provide your code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @J.Afarian I've added code. :)

Comment: Is this your base code? Or the code after the id's are lost? I mean, you have those hidden ID's explicitly stated in your code snippet above.

Comment: It's  a base code. I've seen on IE's developer tools that IDs are hiding as in the 1st screen.

Comment: They're hidden because you've explicitly set them as hidden. Look at the code snippet you posted....

Comment: Please take a look at the first screen - there is no attribute "hidden", but ID disappear.